# call a laravel 4.2 controller method using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

hello i have this div or anchor tag that when click i would get its id and i needed that id to be stored in my laravel session since the id is a javascript i needed to use ajax so that i could somehow make php see the value of id. In my controller `NSAController`i have created this simple method

```
public function set($name)
{
    Session::put('TIDN' , $name);
}
```

i am thinking if maybe i can call this method in my ajax? any ideas on how i can make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make an AJAX request to that function?

You will need to create a route which references it, then call that:

```
Route::post('ajax/setid', 'NSAController@set');
```

You would then use Javascript on your page to send the request, along with the ID. You would either send this as a variable, or include it in the URL to access it directly in your function definition:

```
Route::post('ajax/setid/{name}', 'NSAController@set'); 
//Now $name will be available in your function
```

And you would make the request to: `ajax/setid/10`.

If you are asking speccifically how to do the AJAX request, it would depend on your library. With Jquery it is as simple as something like:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/ajax/setid",
   data: { id: newid }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
   //Done
});
```

Or, if you include the var in the URL:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/ajax/setid/"+newid
})
.done(function( msg ) {
   //Done
});
```

Any AJAX calls to this URL will now call your function in your `NSAController`.

If you are using something like Jquery, you can wrap that AJAX call in a click function on your button:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var newid = $(this).attr('id') //Returns ID of clicked element

    //AJAX code here
});
```